# Prove or disprove logical statements

Tags: logic, proof-writing

How do I show that these two statements are true or false:

$$[\forall yGy \wedge \exists xHx]\iff\exists x [\forall yGy \wedge Hx]$$

and $$\forall x[ Px \implies \exists yQxy]\implies\forall x\exists y [Px \implies Qxy]$$

I know there is some sort of quantifier distribution rule that makes this an easy proof but I've tried it a few times and I can't get it right.

EDIT: Here's what I have tried.

(1) $[\forall yGy \wedge \exists xHx]\iff\exists x [\forall yGy \wedge Hx]$

$\implies $$[\exists yGy \wedge \exists xHx]\iff[\exists x\forall yGy \wedge \exists xHx]$

$\implies $$[\exists yGy \wedge \exists xHx]\iff[\exists yGy \wedge \exists xHx]$

(2) $\forall x[ Px \implies \exists yQxy]\implies\forall x\exists y [Px \implies Qxy]$

$\implies$$[\exists x Px \implies \exists yQxy]\implies\exists y [\exists xPx \implies Qxy]$

$\implies$$[\exists x Px \implies \exists yQxy]\implies [\exists xPx \implies \exists yQxy]$

Comment: I assume that $Gy$ means that $y$ has property $G$ (or something similar).  It would be good to show us what have you tried.

Comment: @Thanassis Yeah I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases the two statements are logically equivalent. Both are instances of a couple of general Prenex laws:

$Q \land \exists x P(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists x (Q \land P(x))$

$Q \rightarrow \exists x P(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists x (Q \rightarrow P(x))$

Where Q is any formula that does not have $x$ as a free variable.

If you can't use these Prenex laws as given, you need to either use some formal semantics to prove their equivalence or you could try a formal derivation from one to the other and vice versa.

As far as quantifiers distributing over logical connectives, we do have that:

$\exists x (P(x) \vee Q(x)) \Leftrightarrow \exists x P(x) \vee \exists x Q(x)$

So for the second one you can do:

$\forall x (Px \rightarrow \exists y Qxy) \Leftrightarrow \forall x(\neg Px \vee \exists y Qxy) \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\exists y \neg Px \vee \exists y Qxy) \Leftrightarrow \forall x \exists y (\neg Px \vee Qxy) \Leftrightarrow \forall x \exists y (Px \rightarrow Qxy)$

(The second step uses Null Quantification: $\exists x Q \Leftrightarrow Q$ if Q does not contain any free variable $x$)

But unfortunately the existential does not distribute over the conjunction, so you can't do something like this for the first pair. Again, you will either have to assume the Prenex Laws directly, and if you can't you have to either use formal semantics or do a formal derivation.  Are you told what method you have to use?

Comment: No, there were no requirements as to what methods I was supposed to use. Thanks for the input!